# How do I pipe `dos2unix` into `while read` in bash?

Tags: bash, dos2unix

Right now, I'm trying to fix an issue in [my PrintBans.sh script](https://gist.github.com/PatPeter/421adef06c75965487dd62df9b7a3480).

The problem is, the program that generates this file saves it with \r\n line endings, so I need the `while` loop to be able to read \r\n lines, otherwise there's an extra \r at the end of the last line which results in the arithmetic failing:

```
 - 621355968000000000")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

I've tried these.

```
while read ban
do
    ...
done < dos2unix $file

while read ban
do
    ...
done < `dos2unix $file`

cat $file > dos2unix > while read ban
do
    ...
done

while read ban
do
    ...
done < dos2unix < $file
```

I also see that some people set `IFS='\r\n'`, but this did not work for me.

Is it impossible to pipe files through dos2unix without overwriting the original file?

Comment: `dos2unix < $file | while ...`

Comment: BTW, `IFS=\r\n` doesn't work, but `IFS=$'\r'` would have. Quotes matter.

Comment: @Cyrus, ...when showcasing that, it's probably worth linking to [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) so folks who are setting variables in  that `while` loop  know what they need to adjust so those variables persist past  the  loop's exit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Okay, I solved a problem and created a new one. ;-) That's better with bash: `while ...; do ... ; done < <(dos2unix < "$file")`

Comment: @Cyrus This is black magic. Thank you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry, I tried both ' and " and forgot to quote them when I surrounded it with backticks.

Comment: @PatPeter, `IFS='\r'` wouldn't work either -- the `$` in `IFS=$'\r'` is important. BTW, `$( )`  has been a mandatory part of the POSIX sh standard since its initial publication in 1992 and resolves the quoting problems introduced by backticks.

Comment: ...btw, you could use `IFS=$(printf  '\r')` on all POSIX shells, though outside the few shells (like ksh93) that optimize away the fork cost it's a hefty  performance cost to pay over `IFS=$'\r'` for that extra portability.

Comment: No need of dos2unix nor cut, while IFS=';' read name idip end_time reason admin start_time ... The '\r' come with the last value start_time so start_time="${start_timef%$'\r'}".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Literal Answer: Pipe Through!

If you don't tell `dos2unix` the name of the file it's working with, it can't modify that file in-place.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "No carriage returns here: <$line>"
done < <(dos2unix <"$file")
```

Redirections are performed *by the shell* before a program is started, when you invoke  `dos2unix <input.txt`,  the  shell  replaces file descriptor 0 with a read  handle  on `input.txt` before invoking `dos2unix`  with  no arguments.

<sub>If you wanted to be **really** paranoid (and pay a performance cost for that paranoia), you  could prevent a hypothetical nonexistent  dos2unix that modified a file descriptor received on stdin in-place from doing so by making it `<(cat <"$file" | dos2unix)`, such that `dos2unix` is reading from a FIFO connected to the separate executable `cat`, rather than straight from the input file. Needless to say, I don't ever advise this in practice.</sub>

---

#### Better Answer: Don't

You don't need `dos2unix` (which -- with its default in-place modification behavior -- is meant for human interactive users, not scripts); the shell itself can strip carriage returns for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- not /bin/sh; needed for $'' syntax and [[ ]]

while IFS= read -r line || [[ $line ]]; do
  line=${line%$'\r'}
  echo "No carriage returns here: <$line>"
done <"$file"
```

- `${var%expr}` is a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) which strips any trailing instance of the glob expression `expr` from the contents of the variable `var`.
- `$'\r'` is [ANSI C-like string](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings) syntax for a carriage return. Using that syntax is important, because other things that look like they might refer to a carriage return *don't*.

  - `\r` outside any kind of quoting context is just the letter `r`.
  - `"\r"` or `'\r'` are two characters (a backslash and then the letter `r`), not a single carriage return.
- `[[ $line ]]` is a ksh extension adopted by bash equivalent to `[ -n "$line" ]`; it checks whether  the variable `line` is non-empty. It's possible for `read` to return false while still populating a line if you have a partial line without any terminator; as l0b0 points out, line *separators* rather than *terminators* are common on Windows. This ensures the last line of a file is processed even if it doesn't end in a newline.

Comment: You probably want `|| [[ -n "$line" ]]` on the first line since Windows uses line *separators* rather than line *terminators.*

Comment: Wow, such a comprehensive answer! Thank you so much. I do have a few questions though, such as what's the difference between `#!/bin/bash` and `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (you said not to use #!/bin/sh which I agree with)?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` uses the first version of bash in the PATH. If you're running MacOS, `/bin/bash` will be the ancient 3.2 release, whereas `#!/usr/bin/env bash` will run a modern release if it's been installed, as via [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or (my personal favorite) [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/).

Comment: Re: suggested edit -- `<$file` may or may not work (depending on shell release) if the name contains spaces, can evaluate as a glob, etc; much safer to use `<"$file"`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the context of your script on github, assuming none of the fields of your CSV file contain a CR character, you just have to put CR in `IFS`.

Change:

```
while read ban; do ...
```

to:

```
while IFS=$'\r' read -r ban; do ...
```

For the same price, you can get the split of ban into six fields with:

```
while IFS=$';\r' read -r name idip end_time reason admin start_time remaining; do
    name=${name/,/\\,}
    ticksToDateString "$end_time"
    ...
```

Comment: The file is generated by a program running on mono, which results in `\r\n` line endings. When my while loop parses each line, there's an extra `\r` in the last cell that's ruining my arithmetic because it breaks it across two lines.

Comment: Is it another unrelated issue with your code, or do you mean there is something wrong with the code I gave you in my answer? I don't see anything in it that could add that `\n` since it is the line delimiter for `read`.